# Adding to a 2 dimensional array with unshift

Tags: javascript

I have a 2 dimensional array:

```
var sH = [['two'],['three']]
```

and I want to add 'one' to the start/top so my array ends up as

```
 [['one'],['two'],['three']]
```

Using [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) like so

```
sH[0].unshift('one');
```

produces an array where 'one is inserted but 'two' is in the second column rather than the first (ie [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) rather than [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)[0])
I've looked and searched and experimented but I cannot see how to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `sH[0].unshift` will affect the bound object - which is an array ( the first of the existing two (two, three); which is two)

In other words, using that method you adds the "one" to the first existing child array which is "two", producing 
[['one', 'two'], 'three']

To produce [['one'], ['two'], ['three']] you should use `sH.unshift('one');`

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps I misunderstand, but don't you just want to do the following?

```
sH.unshift(['one'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var sH = [['two'],['three']];
sH.unshift(['one']); // [["one"], ["two"], ["three"]]
sH.push(['four']); // [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong with your sh index.

It should be `sh.unshift(['one']);`

This will insert an array containing "one" string.